# jq: How to match one of array and get property value

Tags: json, jq

I have some JSON like this:

```
{
  "x": [
    {
      "name": "Hello",
      "id": "211"
    },
    {
      "name": "Goodbye",
      "id": "221"
    },
    {
      "name": "Christmas",
      "id": "171"
    }
  ],
  "y": "value"
}
```

Using jq, given a name value (e.g. Christmas) how can I get it's associated id (i.e. 171).

I've got as far as being able to check for presence of the name in one of the array's objects, but I can't work out how to filter it down

```
jq -r 'select(.x[].name == "Christmas")'
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**`jq`** approach:

```
jq -r '.x[] | select(.name == "Christmas").id' file
171
```

---

The function `select(boolean_expression)` produces its input unchanged if `boolean_expression` returns `true` for that input, and produces no output otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It can also been done like:

```
jq '.x[] | select(.name == "Christmas").id'
```

Also you can try this at link [online jq play](https://jqplay.org/)